# threading in titanium without alloy

Tags: javascript, android, ios, multithreading, titanium

the following code is a loop which I have to run which will update my UI with the correct meta data title of a song currently played on the radio. I need the loop to run every 10 seconds-ish. I tried setting a timeout of ten seconds and calling my function every ten seconds and that caused my app to crash so I think I have to create a seperate thread. I saw a q & a answer detailing how to do this with alloy here:

```
http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/117199/how-to-create-multithreading-in-mobile-sdk
```

Is there any examples of doing this without alloy or what is the best practise for implementing multiple threads? Code below:

```
function FetchMetaData () {
//while (true)
alert("Am I being fired");
   if (isPlaying && Titanium.Network.online) {
        if  (TitleLabel.text !== streamer.getMetaTitle()) {
            TitleLabel.setText(streamer.getMetaTitle());
        }   
        else {
                //Do nothing
        }
     }   
     else {
           //Do nothing
     }
    //}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

setInterval should do it:

```
function updateView() {
    //your update code
}
setInterval(function() {
    updateView();
}, 10000);
```

What is the titanium log error when your app crashes? It might be because of something other than the setInterval.

Comment: To be clear, [Javascript is single threaded](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/) and timers do not run on separate threads.